# angular-templates ui-router not routing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-template

I have an existing angular/rails app.  Everything works fine, except I just added a new module, and the template will not render.  Below is my code.

views/printers/orders_index.html.erb

```
<div ng-app="printers"> 
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

assets/javascripts/printers/config.js

```
(function() {
'use strict'
  angular.module('printers.controller', [])
  angular
    .module('printers', 
      ['ngAnimate',
       'ui.router',
       'templates',
       'ngResource', 
       'printers.controller',
       'orders.factories'
      ])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
      /* Routes and States*/
      $stateProvider
          .state('printers.orders.index', {
              url: '/printer_orders_index',
              templateUrl: 'orders_index.html',
              controller: 'PrintersController'
          })
      // default fall back route
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('printers_orders_index')
    })
})()
```

assets/javascripts/printers/controllers/printers_controllers.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

  angular
    .module('printers.controller')
    .controller("PrintersController", PrintersController)

  PrintersController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Order']

  function PrintersController($scope, Order){
    Order.query({}, function(response){
      $scope.orders = response.orders
      $scope.printer_id = response.meta.printer_id
    })
  }
})()
```

assets/templates/orders_index.html

(this will not render, it seems it is only rendering the orders_index.html.erb, and the ng-app=printers is not doing anything.)

## Meow

(h1 tags with Meow in between)

I have tried the sprockets issue, but it has been fixed, i cant think of anything else.  Any help would be soooo greatly appreciated!

Comment: why two module in config.js?

Comment: I'm just defining all my modules for printers there.

Comment: Yes but you already define printers.controller in printer_controller.js and also added in dependency then no need to define in config.js

Comment: It's just a design pattern